# Context menu off center when zoomed

Tags: javascript, css, node-webkit

I've built a right click context menu using node webkit's Menu API. The problem I'm having with it is when I increase the zoom of the page, say from 1 to 1.4, the context menu goes off center from my mouse cursor. Has anyone else run into this or have a fix for it?

Here's how I'm generating my menu:

```
// Load native UI library
var gui = require('nw.gui');

// Create an empty menu
var menu = new gui.Menu();

// Add some items
menu.append(new gui.MenuItem({ label: 'Item A' }));
menu.append(new gui.MenuItem({ label: 'Item B' }));
menu.append(new gui.MenuItem({ type: 'separator' }));
menu.append(new gui.MenuItem({ label: 'Item C' }));

// Remove one item
menu.removeAt(1);

// Popup as context menu
$(document).on("contextmenu", function() {
    menu.popup();
})
```

Here's a link to the API reference: https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/menu

Comment: Isn't `menu.popup(10, 10);` a static position anyway ?

Comment: You're right, I didn't mean to copy that part of the example code. Original post has been edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can target the mouse position adjusted for the zoom level, based on:

- https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/2023#issuecomment-71005188
- https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/menu#menupopupint-x-int-y

Fixed code:

```
// Load native UI library
var gui = require('nw.gui');

// window (needed to get zoom level)
var win = gui.Window.get();

// Create an empty menu
var menu = new gui.Menu();

// Add some items
menu.append(new gui.MenuItem({ label: 'Item A' }));
menu.append(new gui.MenuItem({ label: 'Item B' }));
menu.append(new gui.MenuItem({ type: 'separator' }));
menu.append(new gui.MenuItem({ label: 'Item C' }));

// Remove one item
menu.removeAt(1);

// Popup as context menu
$(document).on("contextmenu", function(ev) {

    // transform zoom level into factor
    var zoomFactor = Math.pow(1.2, win.zoomLevel);

    menu.popup(
        Math.round(zoomFactor * ev.clientX),
        Math.round(zoomFactor * ev.clientY)
    );
})
```